# Keeping Slider Carousel Active as Default on WordPress using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a Javascript which acts as a slider carousel

But I want the first slide to active on page load, can someone suggest a modification or add on for this

Adding screenshot for referance.

```js
// Slider navigation JS

jQuery(window).load(function () {
  const imageCarousel = jQuery(".myslider .swiper-container"),
    swiperInstance = imageCarousel.data("swiper");

  jQuery("#slide0").click(function () {
    swiperInstance.slideTo(1);
  });
  jQuery("#slide1").click(function () {
    swiperInstance.slideTo(2);
  });
  jQuery("#slide2").click(function () {
    swiperInstance.slideTo(3);
  });
  jQuery("#slide3").click(function () {
    swiperInstance.slideTo(4);
  });
  
  if (swiperInstance != undefined) {
    swiperInstance.on("slideChange", function () {
      var slide = String(swiperInstance.realIndex);
      jQuery(".slide_nav").removeClass("active");
      jQuery("#slide" + slide).addClass("active");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.slide_nav {
  cursor: default !important;
}

.slide_nav.active {
border: 1px solid #555555;
  border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: white;
}

span.elementor-button-text {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[On Page Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Khh.png)

[On Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHPss.png)

Basically, without clicking I want the lean on us to be active on page load (first one) (without clicking)

Comment: So call the function that clicking on that first item would call, directly then ...?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the first section to be highlighted as the default on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change button class to **slide_nav.active** (currently its slide.nav active)

The javascript is fine.

```
.slide_nav {
  cursor: default !important;
}

.slide_nav.active {
border: 1px solid #555555;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```